# How is a variable name stored in C?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I want to ask how C the variables are stored in C?

To be more clear consider the following code:

```
int main() {
    int a = 1, b;
    b = a + 2;
    return 0;
}
```

For example here in what memory C stores the names of variable places.

eg if `&a=0x12A7`(suppose) `&b=0x123B1`, then how and where does [c](/questions/tagged/c) stores the variable names like in which memory name `a` is stored?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C doesn't store name of the variables. Its the compiler that stores the names of variables in compiler's *symbol table*.
This data structure is created and maintained by compiler.
An [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table#Example) of a symbol table for the snippet

```
// Declare an external function
extern double bar(double x);

// Define a public function
double foo(int count)
{
    double  sum = 0.0;

    // Sum all the values bar(1) to bar(count)
    for (int i = 1;  i <= count;  i++)
        sum += bar((double) i);
    return sum;
}
```

may contain at least the following symbol:

[image]

Comment: A symbol table is a compiletime construct, it doesn't reflect runtime properties. Map files and debug info are sources available to get an idea of symbol names for locations, but they were not meant to be used from within the program.. RTTI and other forms of introspection are, but C doesn't have any form of it

Answer (score 19):

Variable names need not be stored at all!  The compiler can get rid of them entirely.  Imagine, if the compiler is quite clever, it can reduce your entire program to this:

```
int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Note that the effect of this program is exactly the same as your original, and now there are no variables at all!  No need to name them now, is there?

Even if the variables in your code were actually used, their names are purely a convenient notation when you write the program, but aren't needed by the processor when it executes your code.  As far as a microprocessor is concerned, a function like this:

```
int foo(int x, int y) {
  int z = x + y;
  return z * 2;
}
```

Might result in compiled code that does this, in some hypothetical simple instruction set architecture (ISA):

```
ADD # consumes top two values on stack (x and y), pushes result (z)
PUSH 2 # pushes 2 on stack
MULT # consumes top two values on stack (z and 2), pushes result
RET
```

The longer story is that variable names are sometimes stored for debugging purposes.  For example if you're using GCC you can pass the `-g` option to emit a "symbol table" which contains things like variable names for debugging.  But it isn't needed simply to run a program, and it isn't covered by the language standard--it's an implementation feature which differs by platform.

Answer (score -1):

Ok first off if you are just getting your head on strait with C this is where to start:
http://condor.cc.ku.edu/~grobe/intro-to-C.shtml

But that is more practical than your question. To answer that we first ask why variables have addresses. The why here is the stack. For a program to operate return calls must be directed to the appropriate buffer so the the pieces all fit together as designed. Now to what I believe was the original question, that is how the actual address is decided, for the answer to that you would have to understand how the processor is implementing the heap.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management

"Since the precise location of the allocation is not known in advance, the memory is accessed indirectly, usually through a pointer reference. The specific algorithm used to organize the memory area and allocate and deallocate chunks is interlinked with the kernel..."

Which brings us back to the practical side of things with the abstraction to pointers:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

Hope tis gives you a little clearer picture of what's under the hood : )

Happy codding.